# Investigating segfault in Mono when calling a OpenCL method clEnqueueTask in linux

Tags: c#, mono, segmentation-fault, opencl

In an attempt to speed up some of my mathmatical routines in my program, I was hoping to try shifting some array division onto the GPU.  The environment I am developing in is a linux (Arch) using monodevelop and using the [OpenTk](http://www.opentk.com/) library when is just a P/Invoke wrapper for the opencl C library.

Specifically I am able to do all the initiation, build the kernel without errors or anything reported in the log, setup the memory buffers and setup the kernel arguments.  The problem occurs when I attempt to queue the task using the method "clEnqueueTask" at which time the program segfaults.

At this point I am unsure of how to debug the program since no exceptions are being thrown (which it had been throwing for more mundane errors like missing dll's) so I am at a loss and I looking for a bit of advice.

Many thanks!

Here is the Code...

```
  string vecDivision = @"__kernel void floatDivision(__global float * v1, __global float * v2){
                            // Vector element index
                            int i = get_global_id(0);
                            v1[i] = v1[i] / v2[0];
                          }";

  try{
    fixed(float* srcA = &data[0]){

      ErrorCode err = ErrorCode.Success;
      IntPtr deviceId = IntPtr.Zero;

      int numDevices = -1;

      // get the platform to create the context from
      IntPtr[] platforms = new IntPtr[3];
      uint[] numPlatforms = new uint[3];
      err = (ErrorCode)CL.GetPlatformIDs(3, platforms, numPlatforms);

      // create the context
      IntPtr[] properties = new IntPtr[]{new IntPtr((int)ContextProperties.ContextPlatform), platforms[0], IntPtr.Zero};
      IntPtr context = CL.CreateContextFromType(properties, DeviceTypeFlags.DeviceTypeGpu, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, new ErrorCode[0]);
      if(context == IntPtr.Zero){
        throw new Exception("Count not create CL Context");
      }

      // get the device id
      err = (ErrorCode)CL.GetDeviceIDs(platforms[0],DeviceTypeFlags.DeviceTypeDefault, 1, ref deviceId, ref numDevices);
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not get the CL device");
      }

      // create the command queue
      IntPtr queue = CL.CreateCommandQueue(context, deviceId, 0, out err);
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not create CL command queue");
      }

      // create the memory buffers
      IntPtr ptrA = CL.CreateBuffer(context, MemFlags.MemReadWrite | MemFlags.MemUseHostPtr, new IntPtr(sizeof(float)*length), (IntPtr)srcA   , out err);
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not create CL buffer");
      }
      IntPtr ptrB = CL.CreateBuffer(context, MemFlags.MemReadOnly | MemFlags.MemUseHostPtr, new IntPtr(sizeof(float))       , (IntPtr)divisor, out err);
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not create CL buffer");
      }

      // create the program using the source
      IntPtr lengths = IntPtr.Zero;
      IntPtr program = CL.CreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,new string[]{vecDivision}, ref lengths, out err);
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not create CL program from source");
      }

      // build the program from source
      err = (ErrorCode)CL.BuildProgram(program, 1, new IntPtr[]{deviceId}, "", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not build the CL program");
      }

      // get the build log
      char[] log = new char[2000];
      IntPtr returnSize = IntPtr.Zero;
      fixed(char* logp = &log[0]){
        err = (ErrorCode)CL.GetProgramBuildInfo(program, deviceId, ProgramBuildInfo.ProgramBuildLog, new IntPtr(log.Length), new IntPtr(logp), out returnSize);
      }
      MsgHandling.LogMessage(new string(log).Substring(0,(int)returnSize), string.Empty);
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not create CL kernel");
      }

      // create the kernel object
      IntPtr kernel = CL.CreateKernel(program, "floatDivision", out err);
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not create CL kernel");
      }

      // set the arguments for the program
      err = (ErrorCode)CL.SetKernelArg(kernel, 0, new IntPtr(sizeof(float*)), new IntPtr(&ptrA));
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not set CL first argument");
      }
      err = (ErrorCode)CL.SetKernelArg(kernel, 1, new IntPtr(sizeof(float*)), new IntPtr(&ptrB));
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not set CL second argument");
      }

      // queue up the worker
      IntPtr globalWorkOffset = IntPtr.Zero;
      IntPtr globalWorkSize = new IntPtr(length);
      IntPtr localWorkSize = new IntPtr(64);
      IntPtr eventWaitList = IntPtr.Zero;
      IntPtr eventItem = IntPtr.Zero;
      //err = (ErrorCode)CL.EnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, null, new IntPtr[]{globalWorkSize}, new IntPtr[]{localWorkSize}, 0, null, new IntPtr[]{eventItem});

      // I DIE HERE!
      err = (ErrorCode)CL.EnqueueTask(queue, kernel, 0,null, new IntPtr[]{eventItem});
      // I DIE HERE!

      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not queue CL job");
      }

      // wait for it to finish
      err = (ErrorCode)CL.Finish(queue);
      if(err != ErrorCode.Success){
        throw new Exception("Count not wait for CL job to finish");
      }

    }
```

Update:

I figured it out.  The issue was how I was creating the buffer.  Apparently if you use the option to use MemUseHostPtr you have to use another method to queue up the read buffers, so instead I used the option to copy the memory directly to the GPU memory, probably a better option in the long run anyway.

Comment: When confronted with this, first I cry.  Then I start iterating, commenting out small pieces of code and re-running until it works.  The reason for the segfault is usually in the last thing you commented out.  Or you can post your code and the rest of us can stare at it.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, don't forget to answer your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was how I was creating the buffer. Apparently if you use the option to use MemUseHostPtr you have to use another method to queue up the read buffers, so instead I used the option to copy the memory directly to the GPU memory, probably a better option in the long run anyway.